# the true implementation of MVC in JAVA

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

From week I have been searching of a true explanation and implementation of MVC using java, but something i have noticed is that every one implement it differently, so I would be grateful if you give me a useful link or e-book about it, and I need these questions to be answered :

- How to inform the modal of the changes happen on the view, since the modal is observable adnd not observer ?
- How to inform the view of the changes happen on collections (adding an item to an arraylist), because to add an item this will be happen on the controller handler and the controller is not observable.
- Is it a must to work with MVC in the big projects.

Comment: The model can both be observable *and* observer. Also, the change of the model will be triggered by the controller, but the changes will happen in the model and the model can then notify the view.

Comment: It's important to understand that "Model-View-Controller" is a concept that is rarely actually implemented according to theory, and very often the code is seriously distorted in attempt to fit the theory more closely.  Use it as a general structuring concept, but don't let the tail wag the dog.

Comment: Model-View-Controller became such a fad that people felt like they had to say they were implementing it, even if they didn't understand it or were writing something where it didn't apply.  Because our industry penalizes people for admitting they don't know the current fad, many people got a cursory (or less) reading of something purporting to be an MVC description, and then went on to instruct others, etc.  I recommend understanding the basic ideas as good software design, and being able to spout one academic description for job interviews, and don't worry about it otherwise.

Comment: The best explanation of MVC that I have seen in any language is in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Oriented-Software-Architecture-System-Patterns-ebook/dp/B0014EME7I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1403443071&sr=8-1&keywords=buschmann+patterns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is:

1. The **trigger** for change can be either the controller 
   (=response code for user inputs, such as keyboard/mouse clicks), or application 
   decision. E.g. if you have a text field showing a price, the trigger to change it could 
   be explicit user typing, or a message from the bank.
2. each such trigger updates the model (and the model only). 
   In my price example, it would change the model (that backs the text field).
3. On change - the model fires events, which cause the view to re-render

Thus, to your first question: there's no need to "inform the model that changes happen on the view". The view shouldn't change on its own. The closes thing is keyboard/mouse clicks, that would invoke the CONTROLLER.
To your second question: "how to inform the view of the changes happen on collection" - the  collection should be in the model. The controller would then do "model.addItem" which would fire an event for the view

Regarding the use in big projects... you'd probably get different opinions on it.
"Atomic" components would most likely follow this pattern strictly (button, textfield, or similar custom components). The debate would be about larger scales with complex/compound data. E.g. if my main logic resides on a database, how to I inform various screens that something changed. Both the screen and the database hold complex compound data (e.g. user plus his product recommendations plus shopping cart), and you need to decide on the granularity of events : on some simple applications I settled for the application layer sending 'Entity-level events' (such as 'user changed', 'product changed') to which the UI layer registered directly, so it wasn't 100% classical MVC. On other cases I took the trouble to build a compound Model that exactly reflects the screen data.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I advise you to start at Wikipedia page on [Model–view–controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350441/the-true-implementation-of-mvc-in-java). You will find a decent explain and other links.

For your first questions, you simply have to think about the workflow. The interaction with user occurs is the view. Then on an action of the user the controller takes the input, optionnaly reformats and passes it to the model in a format known to the model. In theory, the model then updates the view (in web applications, the controller collects data from the model and passes it to the view, so the update model -> view is indirect).

For the second, if you are in a situation where the model can directly update the view (Desktop application or specialized components such as java applets) no problem. If the model cannot directly update the view (typical in web applications), the update will be visible on next interaction. And in fact it happens exactly this way, when you see a web page with gauges displaying values constantly up to date : the browser is instructed via javascript or html meta tags to refresh its state at short time intervals. But when you say *to add an item this will be happen on the controller handler*, it is only true is this is caused by an interaction from the user (and the view knows it has to update its state, or is instructed to do so via the controller). But the model can be modified by many other ways, interaction from other users, real time probes, back office operations, etc.

The third question is a bit a matter of opinions. What is true is that separation of concerns is recognized as a good design because the different layers can be developped and tested independently (ot a certain extend). That separation allows to change technology in one layer without changing the others (even if this is often theorical). But IMHO the greatest benefit is that you have plenty of frameworks implementing MVC pattern. Choose one, and the greatest part of boiler plate code will be offered by the framework without you having to write and test it. All that giving a reduction of developpement time and of possibilities of mistakes.

My conclusion will be that (like others said in theirs comments) what is important is understanding the theory **and the theorical benefits** of MVC patterns and separation of concerns. Then depending of what you have to develop and you environment (technologies knowned or allowed) choose a framework that will exempt you to write boiler plate code, and spend the saved time to carefully analyze what all that is for, and what users expect.